# Monitoring Journey entry audience

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, ssjs

I have a journey which audience is an entry data extension. The DE gets populated daily via automation. How can I receive an email if, let's say, less than 200 contacts make it to the journey ?

I was thinking about Ampscript. I have monitoringDE where I store the counting of the audience, this field is called Total.

```
SET @numbercontacts = Lookup ('monitoringDE', 'Total','Total','200')

IF @numbercontacts < 200 THEN --send email--
```

I could do something like that in automation studio, but I see the script activity only works with SSJS. And as far as I know SSJS is for landing pages.  Any ideas ?

Comment: You could utilize the Analytics Builder -> Reports to send you daily interactions of the journey.  This would be a quick solution but would require you to open the resulting csv file to see if the interaction count is <200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you would use the [verification activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/verification_activity/) introduced in the June release. There are various ways to do this :

1. If your data extension is updated by overwrite you can simply set this up as part of your automation.
2. If you add to the existing rows you need an information on your data extension that allows you to discriminate old and new data. Based on that you can create a query that writes the resulting new queries into another data extension by overwrite. The verification would then run on this.
3. To really make sure you count the records that make it into the journey (passing the entry event) you could also use a contact update activity at the beginning of the journey to write the records into your verification data extension. As journey entry sometimes takes longer than expected you would create a second automation that runs about an hour or more after the automation that fires the journey entry.

One of those three ways should work for you. Which is the best one depends on your process setup and user proficiency.

I hope that helps.